# Performance problem with Ubuntu file server

Tags: ubuntu, system-administration

I'm hoping someone can point to a bottleneck for me.
See the attached diagram.
[image: Network Layout]

The Ubuntu server is attached to a bridge, remote to the rest of the network.
Performance all over the network is good, but when I download files from the Server to the MacBook, I get 2MB/s (megabytes/s). That makes moving large files unworkable.

I've been looking at where the slowdown could occur.

Its not the disk (which is Raid5 using mdadm) on the server. I ran some IO tests to check reading and writing from it and got very respectable scores:

First - writing to /data (which is on the raid array):

```
paul@server:/data/tmp$ dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile bs=8k count=1000000 ; sync
1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
8192000000 bytes (8.2 GB, 7.6 GiB) copied, 48.6398 s, 168 MB/s
```

Now reading from a file on the raid array:

```
paul@server:/data/tmp$ dd if=/data/tmp/anothertestfile of=/dev/null 
21653847+1 records in
21653847+1 records out
11086770047 bytes (11 GB, 10 GiB) copied, 55.1461 s, 201 MB/s
```

So its not the disk.
What about the network? Well... here is the speedtest from the server to the internet:

```
paul@server:/data/tmp$ speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Testing from Vocus New Zealand (101.98.130.3)...
Selecting best server based on latency...
Hosted by Vocusgroup NZ (Auckland) [1.37 km]: 5.67 ms
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 202.89 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 172.08 Mbit/s
```

Having my server at the end of a wifi connection getting 200Mb is good enough for my purposes.

The Mac gets 1Gb to the internet because its wired.

I have tested downloading files from the server to the Mac using HTTPS, SFTP (i.e. FTP over SSH) and SMB. All give the same results - about 2MB per second. I have also tested an AppleTV which is wired to the Firewall - it gets 2MB/s from the Server.

Weirdly - I connected into my home network from outside using Wireguard. Then I tried to download a large file directly from the Server, and I got 35MB/s, which is pretty good.

Also, when I *upload* large files to the server from the MacBook, I typically see much faster results - 20-30MB/s. So writing is much faster than reading.

Any ideas where the slowdown could occur?

Thx.
Paul

[EDIT: adding some more stats]

During a download from the server, which is running at about 2MB/s, here are some perf metrics from the server. Bottom line is that the server is very lightly loaded, but still serving files slowly.

IFTOP:

```
                      19.1Mb                38.1Mb                57.2Mb                76.3Mb          95.4Mb
└─bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb┴─bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb┴─bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb┴─bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb┴─bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb─
server.local                              => MacBook-Pro.local                         13.6Mb  14.5Mb  16.2Mb
                                          <=                                            660Kb   653Kb   738Kb
```

TOP:

```
top - 08:57:41 up 9 days, 14:17,  2 users,  load average: 0.16, 0.12, 0.09
Tasks: 208 total,   1 running, 156 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.4 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.7 id,  1.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  1841464 total,    82652 free,   550804 used,  1208008 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2097148 total,  1373180 free,   723968 used.  1023428 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                  
 1089 avahi     20   0   48412   2644   1216 S   1.0  0.1  40:45.24 avahi-daemon                             
25952 paul      20   0 1641140  20908  16224 S   1.0  1.1   0:11.53 smbd                                     
   22 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   2:55.45 ksoftirqd/2                              
  533 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0  10:45.52 rc0                                      
 1464 mysql     20   0 2685192 207700   4976 S   0.3 11.3 478:43.85 mysqld
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check firmware on your router and bridge if it is latest version?

Did you check network card driver on your ubuntu server if it is set to 1000MB full duplex or do you use WLAN too?

Is there something different if you are using network cable or wlan from mac to router about the download speed from ubuntu server?

Comment: Good questions! Router and bridge fully up to date (both are netgear equipment). Ubuntu is 1000Mb. "ethtool eth0" reports "Duplex: Full" and "Speed: 1000Mb/s". There doesn't seem to be a difference between wlan and lan for downloads from the server.

Comment: On WIFI vs LAN for downloads from the server... I have tried this with a Mac and an AppleTV. All 4 possibilities give the same slow results.